# Selector of the parent view is not working when any child is clicked

Tags: android, android-layout

XML of the selector is:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@color/primary_light_transparent" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/primary_light_transparent" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/primary_light_transparent" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/primary_light_transparent" android:state_activated="true" android:state_enabled="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/normal"/>
</selector>
```

And the layout XML is:

```
<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/keypad_6"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
     android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
     android:onClick="onClick" >

     <Button
     android:id="@+id/keypad_6_bt"
     style="@style/Button.Keypad.Numeric"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:onClick="onClick"
     android:text="6" />

    <TextView
     android:id="@+id/keypad_6_tv"
     style="@style/Keypad_Letters"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="bottom"
     android:gravity="center_horizontal"
     android:onClick="onClick"
     android:text="MNO"
     android:textColor="@color/keypad_digits_color" />
</FrameLayout>
```

What i am looking for is that when the child views (Button or TextView) of the `FrameLayout` will be clicked the selector of the FrameLayout should work and should highlight the whole layout.

I am unable to achieve this and looking forward to know how can i do this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add
`android:addStatesFromChildren="true"`
to your **FrameLayout**

Comment: How can we do the same for click handling?

Comment: You want the button/textview click to trigger Parent's onClick?

Comment: Yes. Currently when i click on the child views it does not trigger the click listener of the parent. So i am handling child views too for the same purpose which is bad i think.

Comment: just call `onClick(parenView)` inside the child's `onClick`;

Comment: I think i could not explain what i want to achieve in the last comment. Let me explain again, i have `android:onClick="onClick"` inside `FrameLayout` as you can see in XML above. Now what i want is that when any child `Button`, `TextView` is clicked the `onClick` of `FrameLayout` is called. Without handling the click of `Button` or `TextView`

Answer (score 0):

When the child is being pressed it takes the focus not the parent. *So forget about doing this using a selector*

**My suggestion for you is:** that you have to do it programatically within your `activity` or `fragment` by having a reference for the parent layout and change its background programatically according to the state that you listen to from your child. For example

```
FrameLayout parentLayout = findViewById(R.id.keypad_6);
Button button6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_6_bt);
button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
         if (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN == event.getAction()){
                parentLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            }else if (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP == event.getAction()){
                parentLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.white);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: @ShajeelAfzal .. You are welcome. The idea of asking on StackOverFlow is to get different point of views and share your problem with all users :)

Comment: Right but i said so because you said: `You will not be able to do what you want ` :)

Comment: @ShajeelAfzal .. Actually *Archie.bpgc* answer, was a useful answer for me also. tha's why I voted him up also and I modified my answer.